# Overloading operator * in C++

Tags: c++

I want to overload operator *, in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        double liczba;

    A operator * (int a){
        A b;
        b.liczba = this->liczba * a;
        return b;
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    2*a;
    return 0;
}
```

I get errors, I know that a*2 doesn't cause problems, but how to do 2*a?

Comment: What errors? Please be specific.

Comment: The only operator you defined takes an A-reference left-hand-side and an `int` value right-hand-side, i.e. `A * int`. If you want the reverse to allow `int * A`, define a free-function operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a friend operator:

```
class A{
    public:
        double liczba;

    A operator * (int a){
        A b;
        b.liczba = this->liczba * a;
        return b;
    }

    friend A operator*(int a, A & b);// friend operator
};

A operator*(int a, A & b)
{
    return b * a;
}
```

Ideally, `A & b` would be `const A & b`, but you need to declare the operator you already defined to be `const` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the operator as a non-member function. For example

```
A operator * ( const A &a, int x )
{
    A b;
    b.liczba =  a.liczba * x;
    return b;
}

A operator * ( int x, const A &a )
{
    A b;
    b.liczba =  a.liczba * x;
    return b;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
        double liczba;
};


A operator * ( const A &a, int x )
{
    A b;
    b.liczba =  a.liczba * x;
    return b;
}

A operator * ( int x, const A &a )
{
    A b;
    b.liczba =  a.liczba * x;
    return b;
}

int main() 
{
    A a = { 10 };

    A b = 2 * a * 5;

    std::cout << b.liczba << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a non-member function:

```
A operator*( int i, const A & a ) {
    A b;
    b.liczba = a.liczba * i;

    return b;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://ideone.com/VtZkdw).